# importing table with primary auto_increment value zero to mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, import, export, mariadb

I'm trying to import database dump into my mariaDb 10.2.6 database.
It's a Magento 2 database.

There is this table import:

```
# Dump of table store_website
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `store_website`;

CREATE TABLE `store_website` (
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Website Id',
  `code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Name',
  `sort_order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Sort Order',
  `default_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Default Group Id',
  `is_default` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Defines Is Website Default',
  PRIMARY KEY (`website_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `STORE_WEBSITE_CODE` (`code`),
  KEY `STORE_WEBSITE_SORT_ORDER` (`sort_order`),
  KEY `STORE_WEBSITE_DEFAULT_GROUP_ID` (`default_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Websites';

LOCK TABLES `store_website` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `store_website` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `store_website` (`website_id`, `code`, `name`, `sort_order`, `default_group_id`, `is_default`)
VALUES
    (0,'admin','Admin',0,0,0),
    (1,'my_website','MY_WEBSITE',0,1,1);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `store_website` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This fails giving me a duplicate key 1 error. Obviously it tries to insert the value 0 as a new increment which would be 1 but that is already in the table.
This error appears even though these options are set:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: I'm still having this issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the InnoDB engine does not support the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO mode. It should be supported by MyISAM though.

Note that using zero as a key in a auto_increment column is not a recommended practice, so it is advisable to avoid it. Is it an option to import the data to MyISAM-tables, do whatever to change the zero-keys to positive numbers and then switch to InnoDB?

Comment: the zero comes from the framework I'm using, not sure why they use it though.
maybe it is part of a user error, where it was expected that auto_increment starts with 1. but was set to 0?

Comment: Grrr... Another case where a Framework gets in the way.

Comment: The zero of the table store_website is used very often in the Magento2-code-basis. If the problem is only in that table, it's be easy to modify manually. Anybody knows, if the same issue (0 on auto_increment-column) exist on other tables of M2?